# Expectation of cubic brownian motion: $E[B_t^3]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

At time t, $B_t \sim N(0,t)$. By symmetry, the $E[B_t^3]=0$.

Obviously, we know $E[B_t]=0$ from the question, but I am not sure how to reach $E[B_t^3]=0$ using symmetry of Brownian motion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have that $B_t \stackrel{d}{=} -B_t$ so that
$$\mathbb{E}[B_t^3] = \mathbb{E}[-B_t^3]$$
which implies that $$\mathbb{E}[B_t^3] = 0.$$

Comment: This is beautiful. I was going to point to the moment generating function and the fact that third non-centered moment of a Normal distribution is $\mu^3 + 3\mu \sigma^2$. But your answer is splendid.

Comment: This is very simple and clear, thanks so much.